# Why axios delete/patch not working on server but works locally with laravel

Tags: laravel, axios, hosting

I got this code

```
axios.delete('/replies/' + this.reply.id)
    .then((response) => {
        flash('Successfully Deleted!', 'success');
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

this works perfectly locally, but on server it's not working , not only `delete` also `patch` while `post` works fine locally and on server,

```
axios.patch('/replies/' + this.reply.id, {
    body : this.body
}).then((response) => {
    flash('Successfully Updated!', 'success');
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

This happens for me in three different website on the same hosting, if the delete/patch request is comming from normal blade it works ok even on server, but when i use axios it only works locally not on the server

Notice : only one of the three projects i added the axios code to it, other projects are from open source projects and no one except me suffers from this, so i have to assume it's not the code, it's the hosting itself, what is missing for me to do ?

Comment: Are you seeing any error in the `.catch()` block?

Comment: You using nginx or apache?

Comment: Did you change your Axios URL in production to use your domain url?

Comment: Try by adding _method: patch to your request body

Comment: What errors do your requests return? You can find that out by going to the Network tab on you browser dev tools.

Comment: i don't get anything in catch except 403 you are not allowed to access /replies/1 @Digvijay

Comment: i use apache @KurtFriars

Comment: @livresonltc no i didn't

Comment: @jverbys i get 403 you don't have permission

Comment: I use nginx, but I am sure apache can also configure what HTTP methods are allowed. See if you have some apache config preventing the methods.

Comment: The full request url should look like `http://your-domain/replies/1` not  just `/replies/1`

Comment: @Raffobaffo you are right, add your answer so i can accept it

Comment: I just did it. Great it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `_method: patch` to your request.

As suggested in Laravel Routing Docs, in the part of [Form Method Spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a 403 then you might not have the CSRF token in the request that Laravel uses to verify that a request is coming from your application. On production things become more strict then on local environments.

Have a look at: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf

Answer (score 0):

I found that the server is not accepting `patch` and `delete` http requests, so i changed the apache settings and now it's working fine, another option is that you define the method in data and user axios.post

```
axios.post(url, {
 data: this.data,
 __method: 'delete'
})
```

this works too